# Distributed Lock Manager (DLM) for .NET?

Tags: .net, synchronization, locking, distributed

I've been examining several DLM's but most of them are written in JAVA or C++. Can't seem to find any service specifically implemented for .NET. Any idea or recommendations for distributed synchronization in .NET?

Comment: Do you need a lockserver or a distributed lock managing framework?

Comment: A lock server. No platform requirement. But needs to have a good .NET client library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into Apache Zookeeper?

> *ZooKeeper is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services.*

There is a .NET API for that at

https://github.com/ewhauser/zookeeper/tree/trunk/src/dotnet

Comment: I have looked briefly at zookeeper but did not see that there was a .NET client library. Will look into it. If it works as expected and can provide the type of synchronization im after then I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Quite late to the party, but for anyone interested now, ServiceStack's Redis client might be useful:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisLocks

Answer (score 0):

Just leaving it here for historic purposes. For a Distributed Lock Management in a .NET/Windows native environment you can use NCache. Its a distributed caching solution built using C# hence in .NET and integrates well with Windows.

Check the following post, its a good start

http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/distributed-locking/

Answer (score 0):

You can check my article about implementing DLM by Redlock.net and Redis [Here](https://towardsdev.com/distributed-locks-manager-c-and-redis-fd3d86cd1250)